# Clamd using +1GB of memory

Tags: firewall, clamav

I've searched around and few similar questions where it was said that a few 100MB memory is normal for clamd.
Now actually I see it using more than 1GB and recently I have frequently that my system starts using swap and in a few instances that I even get swap errors.

How do I know that this memory usage is normal?
It's hogging 1/4th of total memory.

Comment: You might look at this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114709/how-to-reduce-clamav-memory-usage

Comment: Thanks. I had already read that. That doesn't really answer if 1GB of memory is normal. Using clamav instead of clamd might be a workaround but that amount of memory would still be used when mails are received. Setting the resident memory size is clearly a no-no in that answer. I was wondering if old definitions could still hog memory (I doubt but you never know).